# PHP Unit in laravel crashes with message "A facade has not been set"

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to write some simple PHPUnit testing which will test my `User class` and some `DB` queries.

I am receving a `A facade has not been set` on each DB query function call and I dont know why.

Do I forget to import or include a file or is it not possible to run PHP unit with laravel `DB` class ?

`UserTest.php`

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\User;
use Tests\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{

    const TABLENAME = 'user';
    protected static $userid;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
    {
        $user           = new \stdClass();
        $user->name     = "Test 1";
        $user->email    = "test@test.com";
        $user->password = "Password";

        self::$userid = User::createNewUser($user);
    }


    /**
     * Create a user
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testGetUser(): void
    {
        $user = new User(self::$userid);
        var_dump($user);

        if (empty($user)) {
            $this->assertTrue(false);
        } else {
            $this->assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

`User.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use StdClass;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [];

    private $id        = 0;
    private $username  = null;
    private $email     = null;
    private $createdAt = null;
    private $updatedAt = null;

    const TABLENAME = 'user';

    public function __construct(int $userId)
    {
        $user = DB::table(self::TABLENAME)->where('id', $userId)->get();

        $this->id        = $user->id;
        $this->username  = $user->name;
        $this->email     = $user->email;
        $this->createdAt = $user->createdAt;
        $this->updatedAt = $user->updatedAt;
    }

    public function get(string $field): string
    {
        return $this->{$field};
    }

    public function updateUser(stdClass $user): boolean
    {
        $user->id = $this->id;
        $result   = DB::table(self::TABLENAME)->update((array) $user);

        return ($result >= 1) ? true : false;
    }

    public static function createNewUser(stdClass $user): int
    {
        return DB::table(self::TABLENAME)->insertGetId((array) $user);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

in tests file

Comment: I did that and it still throws an error

Comment: I found some answer, what about if you create custom setUp and tearDown methods and implent parent::tearDown() and parent::setUp() in them

Comment: I have create code link here you can visit it and see it
https://codeshare.io/alRgDR
let me know if it works

Comment: @DatoDT can you post it as a answer the link is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. The approach to this was wrong from the begging. I did not use a correct model structure so pure `DB` calls were wrong as we should not use SQL queries within the Laravel project. (Unless absolute necessary) 
After generating a new model and filling the basis based on the Laravel documentation it worked and tests started to pass.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
use Tests\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{

    const TABLENAME = 'user';
    protected static $userid;


    protected function setUp(){
      parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
       parent::tearDown();
    }
    public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
    {
        $user           = new \stdClass();
        $user->name     = "Test 1";
        $user->email    = "test@test.com";
        $user->password = "Password";

        self::$userid = User::createNewUser($user);
    }


    /**
     * Create a user
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testGetUser(): void
    {
        $user = new User(self::$userid);
        var_dump($user);

        if (empty($user)) {
            $this->assertTrue(false);
        } else {
            $this->assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Sadly this did not help and I am still getting
`RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set`